# Detecting Antivirus State

Tags: security, winapi, antivirus

According to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/883792 , MS can detect installed AV using either WMI or a manual method involving registry keys that MS knows about.  Is there an API to access this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=win32+security+center+api) yields [this MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb963845(VS.85).aspx) which appears to be what you're looking for, the Windows Security Center API.  The documentation says Vista only, but I believe this API is also available through the [Windows XP SP2 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570371.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find documentation for it and you want to do some manual digging, you can try executing [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals and then launch the Security Center. It'll show you what keys are read, and what files are accessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Win32 Registry access APIs if you knew the keys.